# Assign super to variable in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, inheritance, superclass

I have this:

```
public class Base {
    public function whoAmI() {
        trace("base");
    }
}

public class Extended extends Base {

    public function Extended() {
        this.whoAmI() //prints extended
        super.whoAmI() //prints base

        var test = super;
        test.whoAmI() //prints extended
    }

    public override function whoAmI() {
        trace("extended");
    }
}
```

The problem is when I do `var test = super`, it seems like `this` is assigned to test instead of `super`.

Is it possible to do the assignment so that `test.whoAmI()` prints "base"?

**Edit**: In the comments it is being said that using super in the way I propose would break overriding. I don't think that's the case. The way I am thinking of it, `super` could be used the same way as `this`. I understand that is not the way super is implemented, but using it that way would not break overriding as people are claiming. So for example the same way this is possible:

```
var test = this;
test.whoAmI();
```

This should be possible:

```
var test = super;
super.whoAmI();
```

It is obviously the choice of the language implementer to not do things this way, and I don't understand the reason why. It doesn't break things, but I guess it does make them more complicated.

I am **not** suggesting type-casting `this` to the `super` class. Obviously that wouldn't work.

Comment: The variable test is pointless, because you already have super. What is your goal here? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It's a bit hard to explain, this is just an example. The class I am working on is a class that keeps track of changes to other classes, including itself. All the classes it watches extend from a base class (including itself) and it calls common methods on each class. The problem is that the 'master' class can't just add itself as it overrides some of the common methods which results in infinite recursion, so I want to make it watch the super class which has the original implementations of the methods.

Comment: it seems like you are confusing objects and classes here. The observer pattern is already implemented in the `EventDispatcher` class, why don't you use that?

Comment: @CameronBall "The problem is that the 'master' class can't just add itself as it overrides some of the common methods which results in infinite recursion" What is stopping you from going `if(objectWatched is MasterClass)`? Does anything extend your master class? Heck, you don't even need the `is`, you could go `if(objectWatched == this)` and you'd know it's the master.

Comment: Nothing, and I did have it working that way. It just seemed nicer to not have to have extra checks.

Comment: @null, I am using the EventDispatcher, as I said the class is complicated and too difficult to explain here. The essence of what I am trying to achieve lies in being able to assign a reference to super, so that is why I used the shorter example.

Comment: If your code works and you're worried about how nice it is, may I suggest [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: @Pimgd According to the OP, this is an example. CodeReview does not accept example code, it's considered hypothetical.

Comment: @CameronBall no the essence of the problem is the problem and trying to achieving that with assigning `super` is your proposed solution, which in itself has problems (it doesn't work). This is an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should explain it regardless if it is difficult or not, because if you don't it is **impossible** to give you a proper answer.

Comment: @Mast I meant for the full code, though.

Comment: @Cameron Ball the implications on overriding are not really part of this question. If you are still interested in solving the underlying problem of your question, please explain it in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are thinking of "this" and "super" as 2 different instances, 2 different things but they in fact point to the same object (obviously) so at the end it's always "this". Using super is just a special keyword that allows the instance to point to the overrided definitions up the inheritance chain, it does not point to a different object. So "super" does correctly its job, it points to the instance and allow you each time you use it to access overrided definitions and that's it. There's of course no point on trying to store that keyword in a variable since in that case it just return correctly the instance it points to which is always "this". 
It's simply a case of misunderstood inheritance principle and I've seen it before, super is mistaken for some kind of instance wrapper up the inheriatnce chain around the object "this" while it's in fact and always the same object.

Comment: This is a good answer. I think the confusion stems from (at least in my case) the fact that this.someMethod() and super.someMethod() look very similar, so it is incorrectly assumed that super is like this but on the parent.

Comment: In most cases you can think of super as a one time switch that turns off overrided definitions and that's really all it does.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

If this were possible, then overriding methods wouldn't be possible!

---

For example, take this function...

```
public function test(a:Object):void {
    trace(a.toString());
}
```

You'd only get `[object Object]` back if your idea was how things worked.

Comment: How doe having a reference to super makes overriding methods impossible?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how your example shows it can't be possible.

Comment: If somehow assigning a superclass reference of an object to a variable would be enough to make it always call the superclass functions, how do you ever know what you have in your hands? You'd say that this example function always takes an object, so everything that goes in there is an object **and nothing else**. Clearly this breaks overloading because overloading requires that subclasses provide their own implementation - but this function wouldn't take subclass-instantiations.

Comment: @CameronBall basically `super` is just special. It takes a object and says for any functions that they should use the function definitions defined by the superclass of the object instead. This rule is lost the moment you exit the statement, so when you assign the result of `super`, you just get the object back.

Comment: I still don't get it. To me the type of the superclass (in my example) would simply be Base. So why isn't var = super; trace(test) just [object Base] the same way trace(super) would be.

Comment: @CameronBall Two ways to go about it: "It just is that way", and "`super` is only valid for one statement."

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understand what you mean your question is more about language definition and specification.

Look at this exemple in c# that explain how you can manage more precisely overriding in c# :

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/csharp/U33Y020413-Understanding-virtual,-override-and-new-keyword-in-C

But 
let's explain a litlle how it's work.

when you extend a class, it's like if you create an object composed of all the object in the inheritance tree so if `B extends A` and `C extends B` you have two objects like this:

(B+A) and (C+B+A) with hierarchy between each other B->A and C->B->A. Super is just a way to ascend in the hierachy.

When you cast a C in A for example. In memory you always have an object (C+B+A) but interpreted as A. When you override you just say that a method in child has an higher priority than in parent.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downcasting `this` manually to any of your class's predecessors. The pointer will still be equal to `this` but the methods called will use the class table of the class used to downcast.

```
public class Extended extends Base {

    public function Extended() {
        this.whoAmI() //prints extended
        super.whoAmI() //prints base

        var test:Base = this;
        test.whoAmI() //should print base
    }

    public override function whoAmI() {
        trace("extended");
    }
}
```

Should your `Base` extend something, which methods are known **or** the superclass is `dynamic`, and there is code that adds methods to `prototype` of a class, you might use such a downcast to call a superclass's method that might not be there at compile time, but make sure you first call `hasOwnProperty` in case of a dynamic class to determine whether a method or property exists.