# Why does assigning a reference to super make overriding impossible?

Tags: oop, inheritance, overriding

I was trying to get an answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29984200/assign-super-to-variable-in-as3/29984519?noredirect=1#29984519) question, and people keep claiming that being able to do something like:

```
test = super;
test.someMethod();
```

Where test.someMethod() will call super's implementation of someMethod, breaks overriding.

I don't see how having things work that way could make overriding methods impossible? Can someone please explain clearly what consequence of doing things the way I propose stops overriding from working?

**Edit:** I am not contesting that it is impossible, clearly it is. What I want to understand is **why** having things work this way is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know action script but I'll hazard a guess.

In all of the documentation that Google has provided me, `super` has always been referred to as a statement. This puts it on an equal footing with `switch` and `if`. However, `super` is obviously different from `switch` and `if` which also implies to me that `super` has some special behavior that allows it to do what it does. This also implies to me that you shouldn't be able to assign it to a var. That you can is probably an oversight in the language or an example of how flexible the language is.

As for those who say that being able to alias super would break OOP, and specifically overriding, I think it's all just a big misunderstanding.

You think that doing `var test = super` gives you an alias for `super`. As in `test` will act as if it were a new `super` statement, despite it not being in the language grammar. However, the others seem to think that all you did was grab `this` type-casted (is that even a thing in action script?) to the super class.

In their mental model, what you want would break overriding since casting an object to a super class should only hide sub-class methods. It should not change the behavior of the ones that are still visible.

All of this being said, I believe that the reason that `var test = super` doesn't work the way you expect it to is because `super` isn't meant to be used as an expression (something that could be on the right-hand side of an `=`) and your use of it as an expression caused weird stuff to happen.

Comment: Yes, in my head "super" should act the same as "this", except it gives you access to the parent's implementations of the methods. I think the reason I felt it worked that way was because of syntax like super.someMethod() - it looks a lot like this.someMethod()

Answer (score 0):

1) Because you don't know it's assigned to super.

2) How does `super == this` work if you can do what you say? Is it true? Is it false? Is there any way to detect you're dealing with the superclass?

---

Theoretically it could be implemented as you say. Simply make all references contain multiple pointers - one to the object instance, one to the function table of the object.

But this makes the language so much more complicated! All just to facilitate bad design.